# Python 3: Syntax logic behind reference/pointer to next node in Linked List

Tags: python, pointers, reference

I'm learning about Linked Lists in Python 3. Here's a code snippet (not mine):

```
Class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
      self.data = data
      self.next_node = None

Class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
      self.head = Node()

def add(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    current_node = self.head
    while current_node.next_node != None:
      do something...
```

What I don't quite understand is the part with `while current_node.next_node != None:`

Is this a case of an instance variable used like some sort of function applied to another variable? And how can it be applied when `next_node` is initialized as `None`? I understand the logic behind Linked Lists as a data structure, but I don't understand the logic behind the syntax.

EDIT:
Thank you all for the answers! I realize that I wasn't clear enough with what I'm actually wondering. The code snippet is just a snippet, and I have the rest of the code working as it is supposed to (never mind the wrong indentation in this post).

What I can't understand is how *current_node.next_node* means to go to the next node from the current one. I understand **what** is does but not **how** it does it. What's the actual underlying structure/principle? How is the pointer actually assigned to the first element?

Hope it makes more sense, I'm not too familiar with the jargon.

Comment: For clarity, can you fix the indentation on the `add` method (can't propose an edit with only indentation changes).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "an instance variable used like some sort of function applied to another variable". `current_node` is a variable pointing to an instance of Node, and `next_node` is an attribute of that instance. What are you confused about?

Comment: I suspect it's that the the `current_node` `Node` instance is instantiated with `next_node = None` so the while loop will never be entered. What's been missed is that the instance can be modified and add called multiple times I think.

Answer (score 1):

current_node is simply an instance of a Node object and has next_node as an attribute.
Here we have a linkedList with a head and in add(self, data) function we build a new_node with the corresponding data then you assign a pointer to the first element of your linkedList (which is current_node) and start iterating over your list.

> And how can it be applied when next_node is initialized as None

Well in your code next_node is None but it's not the case always!
and add function can be completed as follow :

```
while current_node.next_node != None:
  current_node = current_node.next_node
current_node.next_node = new_node
```

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you mentioned one-way linked list is searched from the start to the end which is marked by `None` as the value of the field `next`. It is a field (variable being a part of the object) not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The part with `while current_node.next_node != None:` is just a loop looking for the end of the Linked List.

You initialise your List with `self.next_node = None`, it means the List is empty.

Then when you `add` an element, you loop through every element of your list to find the place where you need to put it. When you find  the value `None`, it's the end of the list, that's where you have to put your new element. (assuming no element as the value `None`).

Here `next_node` is just a field of your class Node